# Accidental navigation mode change

Tags: 3d-view

I sometimes accidentally change the behaviour of the view port navigation. I don't know how I do it, nor how to reset it.

The behaviour is different insofar that if I press the middle mouse button and move the mouse, the view does not rotate around a point that lies somewhere where I'm looking at but more like around a point in the "camera" of the view port.

It's like looking around in a first person shooter.

What mode is this and how do I change it back?

Comment: Do you have pressed Shift+F?

Comment: No, this is walk mode right? The behaviour is similar though.

Comment: I think it has to do with the dolly mode. I will try to reproduce the behaviour later when I have time.

Comment: @CoDEmanX yes looks like